# binary parsing for RTCM msg in python

Tags: python, parsing, binary, gps

Want to parse RTCM binary data. Using ublox gps receiver. Looking for the RTCM start byte D3, by using

```
if buffer[i] == 0xd3
```

But seems it does not match, and not entering the loop at all. I tested with

```
if buffer[i] == b'xd3'
```

But it is not working too.

Tested in powershell prompt (anaconda) to check like this:

```
>>> bin_Str = b'\x24\x47\x50\xd3'
>>> bin_Str
b'$GP\xd3'
>>> bin_Str[3] == 0xd3
True
```

So, seems it should match 0xd3. I have checked the log. There ARE D3 in the binary data. Can anyone please help? Would be really grateful.

Comment: `b'xd3'` is not a single byte. It's 3 bytes, from the ASCII characters `x`, `d` and `3`. You wanted `b'\xd3'` (the backslash and `x` combination before 2 hex digits is a valid hex escape sequence for a single byte). Not that comparing that against `buffer[i]` would work, because in a `bytes` object individual elements are actually integers. However, we can't help here because we have nothing to go on as to what `buffer` actually *is*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for being so late. There was actually a basic problem with that. The binary file I was supposed to read was altered - it was not what I thought I was reading. After founding that it solved the problem. But thanks anyway. Would be helpful in future I am sure. Conversion brings some difficult to detect issues.